# Non-Conformable Arrays when Doing Matrix Multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to implement Kernel Ridge Regression in R.

The formula is:

```
alpha <- ((lambda.I + K)^(-1)) * y
```

Lambda = 0.1. I = identity matrix the same size as K. y is a feature vector that has the same number of rows as K.

So I tried this in R:

```
I <- diag(nrow(df_matrix)
lambda <- 0.1
alpha <- (lambda * I + df_matrix) ^ (-1) * df_vector
```

I get the following error

```
Error in (0.1 * I + df_matrix)^(-1) * df_vector : non-conformable arrays
```

Here's some information on my dataset

```
> nrow(df_matrix)
[1] 8222
> ncol(df_matrix)
[1] 8222
> nrow(df_vector)
[1] 8222
> nrow(I)
[1] 8222
> ncol(I)
[1] 8222
> class(df_matrix)
[1] "matrix"
> class(df_vector)
[1] "matrix"
```

Comment: The syntax for inverting a matrix in R is not `^(-1)`. And `*` is not matrix multiplication in R.

Comment: what is ncol(df_vector)? If you assume it is 8222 or 1, the code seems to work

Answer (score 6):

I bet you want to have here matrix inversion, which is `solve(m)`, instead of element-wise (`m^(-1)`). Also, matrix multiplication (`%*%`) instead of element-wise (`*`). So, altogether is

```
alpha <- solve(lambda * I + df_matrix) %*% df_vector
```

Comment: And of course, `solve(lambda * I + df_matrix, df_vector)` would be more sensible/efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use matrix multiplication, `%*%`. In addition you also need to use `solve` to compute inverses as raising to the power minus one will just do element wise reciprocals. e.g.:

```
K <- matrix(runif(9),3)
y <- matrix(runif(3),nrow=3)

solve(lambda*diag(nrow(K))+K) %*% y
            [,1]
[1,]  0.50035075
[2,] -0.04985508
[3,]  0.74944867
```

Answer (score 1):

To transpose a matrix, the matrix has to be quadratic and the determinant has to be different to zero. If you matrix df_matrix fullfil these requirements, then

```
alpha <- solve(lambda * I + df_matrix) %*% df_vector
```