# Non-Conformable Arrays in While Loop (R)?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement gradient descent manually and am running into the following error:

> Error in beta - ((alpha/6132) * sum(yhat - y) * x) :
> non-conformable arrays

My code is

```
while(itr < 20){
beta <- beta - ((alpha/6132)*sum(yhat-y)*x)
t <- t(beta)
yhat <- t(t%*%x)
itr <- itr+1
}
```

Where y and yhat are both matrices with the same number of rows (6132) and columns (1), and beta is a set of 12 arbitrary beta values to be optimized iteratively and x is a matrix containing 12 predictor variables.

Here is the code detailing this:

```
beta <- as.matrix(1:12)
t <- t(beta)

x <- as.matrix(t(bike))

x <- rbind(1, x)

yhat <- t(t%*%x)
y <- t(y)

alpha <- 0.01
```

x is a matrix with 12 columns and 6132 rows.

Any help/advise is appreciated.

Comment: you will need to share more data for initial values of your variables (alpha, beta, etc) if you want answers. the error message says your have non compatible dimensions, maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183762/non-conformable-arrays-when-doing-matrix-multiplication-in-r/37184082) can help

Comment: Hi Nate, I just updated the post with more information on beta and alpha values. Hopefully that clarifies my problem. I will look at the post you shared.

Comment: We do not know anything about `X`. The problem states one of the following: `length(y) != length(yhat)`, `dim(x) != dim(beta)`. You might be trying to do proper matrix multiplication, in which case you should look at `help("%*%")` since `%*%` is the matrix multiplication operator.